# Finding the Equations for Planes of Different Faces of a Box

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, 3d

The question is as follows:

> The illustration at bottom shows a rectangular box, three of whose edges coincide with the coordinate axes, and one of whose vertices is $(3, 6, 4)$. Give an equation for the plane containing the front face of the box. Do the same for the top and right faces.

[image]

For the front face, I found the slope by calculating $\frac{\Delta z}{\Delta y}$ which led me to $\frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$. However, I don't know whether it should be $\frac{2}{3}x$, $\frac{2}{3}y$, or $\frac{2}{3}z$ nor do I know what the equation will result in a $x$, $y$, or $z$ value.

I hope that by receiving assistance in this part of the problem, then I may be able to calculate the equations for the other planes of the two other faces. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You’ve computed a slope of the box’s diagonal, not of any of the faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planes don't have "slope", they have normal vectors.  But this problem is easier than that.  The front face is parallel to the $yz$ plane and has $x$-intercept $3$.   Every point in that plane has $x$-coordinate $3$ and there is no restriction on the $y$ and $z$ coordinates.  So the equation of the plane is $x=3.$

Answer (score 1):

You can write the equation of a plane by knowing a point that belongs to the plane ${\bf x}_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and a vector perpendicular to the plane ${\bf n}$. The equation then becomes

$$
{\bf n}\cdot({\bf x} - {\bf x}_0) = 0 \tag{1}
$$

For example, for  the front face

- ${\bf x}_0 = (3, 0, 0)$ and
- ${\bf n} = (1, 0, 0)$

The equation of the plane is then

$$
(1, 0, 0)\cdot[(x, y, z) - (3, 0, 0)] = 0 \\
\Rightarrow ~~~x - 3 = 0
$$

I will leave the other two for you to work out

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still not sure about why you have ${\bf n} = (1, 0, 0)$. Furthermore, why can't we use the point $(3, 6, 4)$ and use the slope that I calculated?

Comment: ${\bf n}$ is any vector perpendicular to the plane. As for the point, you can use any point that is on the plane. You can use ${\bf x}_0 = (3, 6, 4)$ the result will be the same